# YOCTO: launching menuconfig open an empty terminal

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using YOCTO to build my environment and when trying to bring-up the menuconfig a black empty window pop-up instead of the menuconfig menu.

I execute the next command under /yocto/build/ directory:

```
[]$ bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

more details:

1. I am using UBUNTU machine with bash
2. I am working on the machine remotely over VNC-viewer so it maybe related to the display configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you ssh from a terminal and then try to use bitbake -c menuconfig? If I recall correctly, it has ncurses as dependencies for this.

Comment: Hi
from SSH (using tera-term) It seems that something is running in the background but still cant see the menu of the menuconfig. instead I have a line at the bottom of the terminal that say "[devshell- 0:devshell-9080*"

Answer (score 2):

SO,
it seems that the default terminal was "gnome" and after changing the terminal so "xterm" it is working.
because the bitbake cleaning the environment so I changed the terminal in /conf/local.conf:

```
OE_TERMINAL="xterm"
```